# How to properly connect JSON configuration file to project without using .NETCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project which I have a custom JSON config file that I would like to incorporate into my project without using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. I am fairly new to this but I would like to avoid using any .Net Core methods or routes.

Below are snippets are the files involved:

Web.Config

```
<appSettings configSource="Config\base\appsettings.json"></appSettings>
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "siteURL": "https://helloworld.com",
  "TokenSecretKey": "justanothersecret",
  "URI.Key": "anotherkey",
  "ClientTokenSharedSecret": "somevalue",
  "TwoFactorSessionExpirationInMinutes": "43200",
  "Email.From": "noreply@thatonesite.com",
  "Email.Server": "192.168.1.1",
  "Email.Server.User": "user",
  "Email.Server.Password": "pword",
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
```

My aim is to have these settings incorporated in the project and be able to use where ever in the project.

Comment: I'd just deserialize the json file into an object and use that.

Comment: @SamAxe so how would I access the deserialized object within my project for use?

Comment: One of the nice things about using the built in config files is they cannot be downloaded. To prevent exposure you will need to ensure your custom config json files cannot be downloaded. If your only reason for using the json file is so you don't have to learn built in config stuff then I would rethink your approach.

Comment: @quaabaam I cannot use a .NET Core approach for this project.